# Spring JPA not releasing connection from HikariP pool

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I am using springboot version 2.1.3 and i am using JPA repo for Pagination by extending PagingAndSortingRepository . so when ever i request from my JPA repo which is managing pagination it gives me proper response but when i check my hikari pool it always keep my pagination one request on pool.

> HikariPool - Pool stats (total=50, active=21, idle=29, waiting=0)

Below is my JPA repo

```
    public interface APENRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<EnplateDetails, Long> {

    Page<EnplateDetails> findAll(Pageable paging);


    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM enplate_transits WHERE timestamp BETWEEN :date AND :endDate ", countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM enplate_transits WHERE timestamp BETWEEN :date AND :endDate", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<EnplateDetails> findAllByDates(@Param("date") String date, @Param("endDate") String endDate,
            Pageable pageable);
     }
```

But if i try to access anything from another JPA repo it close connection by default.So if anyone has faced this issue so let me know that i can resloved this.

Hikari Config are below

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=50
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=HikariPool
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=3000
```

Comment: can u add jpa configurations for hikari .

Comment: you must have given minimun active count to , hence hikari is keeping some idle connections

Comment: i have added configuration can you please check now

Comment: Do u want fixed size pooling ? if yes then JPA wont release any connections.

Comment: @MandarDharurkar my concern is that why it is happening when i use pagination otherwise i dont face any issue with JPA repos

Comment: sorry didnt get your concern . can you please elaborate more . Ideally we dont nned to worry about connection closing incase of fixed pool size and HikariPool will take care of that.

Comment: @MandarDharurkar can you provide me any reference to fixed size pool

Comment: remove minimumIdle just use maximumPoolSize which will be treated as fixed pool size